# Model selection: differentiating between two biased coins

Tags: statistics

Suppose you have two "coins" (Bernoulli variables) $X_1 \sim B(p_1)$ and $X_2 \sim B(p_2)$. You're presented with one of the coins at random -- you don't know which, but with probability $p$ it's $X_1$, and $1-p$ it's $X_2$. You may flip it as many times as you want. If you think you have $X_1$, you say so and are again given a coin at random. If you think you have $X_2$, you say so, and the game is over. Your goal is to be able to correctly state that you have $X_2$ in hand.

What's a procedure for playing that both attempts to minimize the number of coin flips made and succeeds with at least probability $p'$? I'd like a procedure where I can compute the expected number of flips (or, at the very least, get a bound on it).